# CONFIRM_NOTIFICATIONS message gives SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE result

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

We're seeing a "service unavailable" error in the last part of Android's in-app purchase message flow and we don't know why.

We've implemented Android's in-app billing and things are working well enough that we get almost all the way through the message sequence:

1) We send the REQUEST_PURCHASE message and get a RESPONSE_CODE of 0 back

2) We receive com.android.vending.billing.IN_APP_NOTIFY

3) We send the GET_PURCHASE_INFORMATION message and also get a RESPONSE_CODE of 0 back

4) We receive com.android.vending.billing.PURCHASE_STATE_CHANGED

5) We send is CONFIRM_NOTIFICATIONS.

We've looked at the sample app (com.android.vending.billing) that Google provides, which says that all we have to supply on a CONFIRM_NOTIFICATIONS message is a String array of notification IDs. The response that we receive from this last message is a com.android.vending.billing.RESPONSE_CODE message in our BroadcastReceiver which contains a response code value of 2 (which maps to "service unavailable"). Why do we get an error from this last message? We're using the static item ID android.test.purchased, if that makes a difference.

The Android log messages are:

06-29 14:20:12.054: DEBUG/iapReceive(21391): Notify, notificationId android.test.purchased

06-29 14:20:12.054: DEBUG/iapSend(21391): sending GET_PURCHASE_INFORMATION with notificationId android.test.purchased

06-29 14:20:13.994: DEBUG/iapReceive(21391): inapp_signed_data is {"nonce":5454,"orders":[{"notificationId":"android.test.purchased","orderId":"transactionId.android.test.purchased","packageName":"com.shinyandroid","productId":"android.test.purchased","purchaseTime":1309382399381,"purchaseState":0}]}

06-29 14:20:13.994: DEBUG/iapReceive(21391): Purchase state changed, notificationId android.test.purchased, SKU android.test.purchased

06-29 14:20:13.994: DEBUG/iapSend(21391): sending CONFIRM_NOTIFICATIONS with notificationId android.test.purchased

06-29 14:20:14.845: DEBUG/vending(18344): [51] RequestRunnable.run(): Got ApiException from async request: Error from backend. Request=com.android.vending.model.AckNotificationsRequest, Response=BAD_REQUEST

06-29 14:20:16.104: DEBUG/vending(18344): [51] RequestRunnable.run(): Got ApiException from async request: Error from backend. Request=com.android.vending.model.AckNotificationsRequest, Response=BAD_REQUEST

06-29 14:20:18.274: DEBUG/vending(18344): [51] RequestRunnable.run(): Got ApiException from async request: Error from backend. Request=com.android.vending.model.AckNotificationsRequest, Response=BAD_REQUEST

06-29 14:20:20.824: DEBUG/vending(18344): [51] RequestRunnable.run(): Got ApiException from async request: Error from backend. Request=com.android.vending.model.AckNotificationsRequest, Response=BAD_REQUEST

06-29 14:20:26.854: DEBUG/vending(18344): [51] RequestRunnable.run(): Got ApiException from async request: Error from backend. Request=com.android.vending.model.AckNotificationsRequest, Response=BAD_REQUEST

06-29 14:20:26.854: WARN/vending(18344): [51] AsynchInAppAckNotifications.onException(): Server error on InAppAckNotificationsRequest: com.android.vending.api.ApiException: Error from backend. Request=com.android.vending.model.AckNotificationsRequest, Response=BAD_REQUEST

06-29 14:20:26.904: DEBUG/iapReceive(21391): Async response code,requestId 5225550415890630760, responseCodeIndex 2

Answer (score 1):

It's been a couple of weeks so I'm no longer 100% sure what we did to fix it, but I believe the problem was a mismatch between the key used to sign the app we'd uploaded (in test mode) to the Android Market and the key we were using to sign the app we ran on the phone.